# Excluding an array element has a specific value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I've a schema which has an array inside and I want to select an item but exclude some of the array elements which have a specific value.

**Sample data:**

```
{
  _id: 1,
  name: something,
  department: management,
  employees: [
    0: { 
      _id: 1,
      name: joe,
      suspended: false
    },
    1: {
      _id: 2,
      name: clare,
      suspended: false
    },
    2: {
      _id: 3,
      name: michelle,
      suspended: true
    }

  ]
}
```

I need to exclude clare and joe and all the others has `suspended:false` from the result. (I need to get the department and it's suspended employees inside)

Here is the code I tried but it didn't work... This code is excluding "suspended" field only. Not the array elements.

```
Department.findOne(
    { name:req.params.department},
    { 'employees.suspended': false }
    , function(err, result){
        if(err) {
            console.log("ERROR");
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("RESULT");
            console.log(result);
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with MongoDB Aggregation framework

```
Department.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      name: req.params.department
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      employees: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$employees",
          cond: {
            $ne: [
              "$$this.suspended",
              false
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]).exec(err, result){
    if(err) {
        console.log("ERROR");
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("RESULT");
        console.log(result);
    }
})
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7sbr-HmuFyw)

Comment: Working correctly on MongoPlayground but it returns an empty array on mongoose.

Comment: @UtkuDemir make sure `req.params.department` has valid string value

Comment: It's my bad. I was trying to match with _id but I didn't know I need to convert string to ObjectId first. So this is working code for $match now:
`$match: { "_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id) }`

Comment: @UtkuDemir excellent. You add more pipeline to aggregation to filter and transform your data

Comment: thanks a lot. I've got one last question... Let's say I want to exclude employees names from the result to reduce response size... What should I do?

Comment: @UtkuDemir You need to add extra stage with [$unset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unset/) operator. [Check it](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AksGc0n-_35)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208980/discussion-between-utku-demir-and-valijon).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $match: { name: req.params.department } },
   {
      $set: {
         employees: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$employees",
               cond: "$$this.suspended"
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Jc-BTGonrRx)

Comment: It's filtering employees correctly but there're lots of departments and I need to select just one by name. I tried to use "$match" but returned an empty array.